# Jquery fails to dynamically create a row cross browser

Tags: jquery, dynamic, html-table, append, row

I have this function for my comment system but it doesn't dynamically add the row...
This is what it looks like:

```
var myTable = $("#adddatacom"+id);
var magicNewRow = document.createElement('tr');
magicNewRow.htmlContent = '<td class="comments"><table><tr><td width="600px"><table><tr><td><?php echo $userimg2; ?></td><td><b><a href="profile.php">You</a>,</b><b style="color:green"> just now</b><br>'+ comMessage.val() +'</td></tr></table></td>';
magicNewRow.innerHTML = '<td class="comments" id="newcomm"><table><tr><td width="600px"><table><tr><td><?php echo $userimg2; ?></td><td><b><a href="profile.php">You</a>,</b><b style="color:green"> just now</b><br>'+ comMessage.val() +'</td></tr></table></td>';
myTable.append(magicNewRow);
```

Comment: what error do you get.. try using firebug and explain

Comment: plus there seems to be only .html() and not .htmlcontent=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your syntax seems in correct

```
var myTable = $("#adddatacom"+id);
var magicNewRow = document.createElement('tr');
myTable.html('<td class="comments"><table><tr><td width="600px"><table><tr><td><?php echo $userimg2; ?></td><td><b><a href="profile.php">You</a>,</b><b style="color:green"> just now</b><br>'+ comMessage.val() +'</td></tr></table></td>');
magicNewRowhtml('<td class="comments" id="newcomm"><table><tr><td width="600px"><table><tr><td><?php echo $userimg2; ?></td><td><b><a href="profile.php">You</a>,</b><b style="color:green"> just now</b><br>'+ comMessage.val() +'</td></tr></table></td>');
myTable.append(magicNewRow);
$('#someelement').append(mytable);
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to append `myTable` too to the document for example

```
document.append(myTable );
```

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work do you know another cross browser method maybe?